# What does "set" mean in programming languages like C#?

Tags: c#, terminology, variables

I've been reading a book about C#. What does the word 'set' mean in the following excerpt?

> **Pattern matching with the switch statement**: Like the if statement, the switch statement supports pattern matching in C# 7.0 and later.
> The  case values no longer need to be literal values; they can be
> patterns. Let's see an example of pattern matching with the switch
> statement using a folder path. If you  are using macOS, then swap the
> commented statement that **sets** the path variable and replace  my
> username with your user folder name:
>
> 1. Add the following statement to the top of the file to import types for working with  input/output: using System.IO;
> 2. Add statements to the end of the Main method to declare a string path to a file, open it  as either a readonly or writeable stream, and
>    then show a message based on what type  and capabilities the stream
>    has, as shown in the following code:
>
> ```
> // string path ="/Users/markjprice/Code/Chapter03"; 
> string path => @"C:\Code\Chapter03"; 
> Write("Press R for readonly or W for write: ");
> ConsoleKeyInfo key = ReadKey(); 
> WriteLine(); ...
> ```

My question is about the following part:

> If you are using macOS, then swap the commented statement that **sets** the path variable and replace my username with your user folder name

Would anybody explain it to me?

Comment: Please, next time, when you post code anywhere, invest some minimal formatting effort to make it readable. But FWIW: "set" can be replaced by "initializes", or "assigns [a certain value to]". And *"the commented statement that sets the path variable"* refers to the first line in the code block section above.

Comment: You mean that "set" is kind of synonym to 'initialize'?

Comment: No. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/set

Comment: @Hossein: not in general , but in this case it would fit.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks about the meaning of a word used in a sentence rather than a keyword in a programming language. Questions like this would be a better fit for the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) community.

Comment: It just means to change the value of a variable to something, to "set its value". It's a verb, the opposite of get. (Later on, you'll learn about "getters" and "setters"). In case you're confusing it with the mathematical notion of a set (a collection of elements) - it has nothing to do with that; those are two different terms that happen to be written the same.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: I am here with Flater, who gave a good reason why not to close this question.

Comment: Two definitions in CS when used as a verb. 1) To set a variable to something is to change its value to that something. Often paired with "get". For example, ccessors that modify attributes and those that fetch the value of attributes are respectively known as setters and getters. 2) To set a bit is to make it true.. To set a variable is change its value to `true` or a true value. To modify it to a false is value is to clear it.

Comment: Re "*You mean that "set" is kind of synonym to 'initialize'?*", You do set a variable to a value when you initialize it, but not the other way around. Initialization usually refers to the first value given to a variable.

Comment: As someone who came from HNQ, not sure if it's only me that feels the title is currently ambiguous because there's [set (mutator method)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) and [set (data type)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)).

Comment: I find it hard to believe that a book about C# has got to the section about "pattern matching with `switch`" without first talking at least a little about *variables*...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This question is one of English semantics, not programming, which initially urged me to vote to close this question as being off topic.

However, because "set" is notoriously the word with the most numerous and widely ranging definitions in the English dictionary ([link](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/english-word-with-the-most-meanings) - 430 definitions in the OED, a whopping 60,000 word long entry), it seems on topic enough to focus on what it specifically means to a programmer when referring to code.

---

Homing in on the intention:

> the [..] statement that sets the path variable

Very specifically, this means the following code (I assume the => was a typo on your part):

```
string path = @"C:\Code\Chapter03";
```

This statement sets a value (`@"C:\Code\Chapter03"`) in the variable (`path`).

That's really all there is to say here. "To set" means "to define a value".

> You mean that "set" is kind of synonym to 'initialize'?

No.

Firstly, you declare a variable:

```
string path;
```

Note that this does not set a value (For those who disagree: I'm ignoring default values here - the compiler warns you about uninitialized variables even if the variable's type has a default value).

Then, when you **first** assign a value, that's what we call initialization:

```
string path;          // declaration
path = "...";         // initialization

// OR

string path = "...";  // declaration + initialization
```

However, "setting" a value happens **any time** you change the value of the variable. After the first time, it's no longer called initialization; but it is still "setting" the value.

All initializations are also inherently a case of setting a value. But not all cases of a value being set are also an initialization.

```
string path;
path = "A";
path = "B";
path = "C";
```

The `path` variable was initialized once but its value was set three times.

Comment: *"To set" means "to define a value"* - I think more formally we would equate it with the operation of **[assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science))**.

Comment: Setting is the same thing as assigning a value. You can assign a value to a variable more than once, or if you prefer, you can say that you have set the value.

Comment: "*this means the following code*" - very specifically, it did refer to the *commented statement*, which would be `string path ="/Users/markjprice/Code/Chapter03";`.

Comment: Re "*means "to define a value".*", "assign" or "give" make more sense than "define"

Comment: Re "*sets a value (`@"C:\Code\Chapter03"`)*", `@"C:\Code\Chapter03"` isn't a value; it's a string literal, a piece of code. The value being assigned is the string `C:\Code\Chapter03`

Comment: Re "*in the variable*", variables don't *contain* a value; they *have* a value. "of the variable" would make more sense.

Comment: Re "*string path;          // declaration*", Is that true in C#? I think this both declares and initializes it (to `null`) That said, it's common to refer to giving the first meaningful value as initialization

Comment: This is not how programming languages use "initialize".

Comment: @ikegami: If a class field member, `string path;` will result in initialization to null (but any assignment, even if multiple, inside the class constructor is also considered initialization).  If inside a method, then `string path;` is uninitialized and any attempt to read from it will result in the compiler loudly telling you so.

Comment: @Bergi: I was zooming in on the declaration and initialization; not the (un)commenting; hence the chosen snippet.

Comment: @ikegami: You're arguing overly specific phrasing to an answer that was written for someone who asked what "set a value" means. The answer is tailored to the asker and is not attempting to set a universal codified terminology to the degree that you're critiquing.

Comment: 1) I wasn't arguing; I suggested fixes to mistakes in the answer. 2) Some of my comments were indeed over specific phrasing. I'm not sure why you think that's a bad thing. The question is literally about terminology, and you introduce a number of terminology mistakes. 3) Such a person would be the least likely to recognize your mistakes and the most likely to absorb them.

Answer (score 6):

In this context, the word *set* means [to *assign*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)) a value to a variable.

This can correspond to several of the many [dictionary definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set) of the English word *set*, as a transitive verb.

- to cause to assume a specified condition, relation, or occupation

  - slaves were *set* free → `foreach (Slave s in slaves) s.IsFree = true;`
  - *set* the house on fire → `house.IsOnFire = true;`
- to cause to assume a specified posture or position

  - *set* the door ajar → `door.Position = AJAR;`
- to adjust (a device and especially a measuring device) to a desired position

  - *set* the alarm for 7:00 → `alarm.Time = new TimeOfDay(7, 0);`
  - *set* a thermostat at 68 → `thermostat.Temperature = 68;`
- to fix at a certain amount

  - *set* bail at $500 → `bail = 500.00;`

The C# language in particular often uses the keywords `get` and `set` in combination to define what it calls a [property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties).